# Section $G:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \text{SU}(1,1)$?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$\mathcal{Remember:}$

---

$i)$ $\mathbb{D}={\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1}\}$

$ii)$ $\text{SU}(1,1)=\left\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\mid \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb C,|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1\right\}$
$={\{\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\theta} & 0\\
 0 & e^{-i\theta}
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 \text{cosh}(t) & \text{sinh}(t)\\
 \text{sinh}(t) & \text{cosh}(t)
\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i\phi} & 0\\
 0 & e^{-i\phi}
\end{array} \right):\phi,\theta\in\mathbb{R}, t\geq 0}\}$

$iii)$ $\rho: \text{SU}(1,1)\to \text{SU}(1,1)/U(1)$, $\rho(g)=gU(1)$ (canonical projection)

---

$\mathcal{Problem:}$

I need to find a section of the form:

$G:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \text{SU}(1,1)$, $z\ \ \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 e^{i\theta(z)} & 0 \\\ 0 & e^{-i\theta(z)}  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 C(z) & S(z) \\\  S(z) &  C(z) \end{array} \right)$ Such that $C^2(z)-S^2(z)=1$, $S(z)\geq 0$, $C(z)\geq 1$

---

$\mathcal{Solution:}$

Let $z\in\mathbb{D}$ be then $z=re^{i\psi}$, where $0\leq r<1$ and $\psi= \text{arg}(z)$.

In this way I can define,
$G:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \text{SU}(1,1)$, $G(z)=G(re^{i\psi})=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 e^{i\psi} & 0 \\\ 0 & e^{-i\psi}  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \sqrt{1+r^2} & r\\\  r &  \sqrt{1+r^2}  \end{array} \right)$. Note that $\sqrt{1+r^2}\geq 1$, $r\geq 0$ and also $(\sqrt{1+r^2})^2-r^2=1$

${Claim:}$ $G:\mathbb{D}\longrightarrow \text{SU}(1,1)$ define a section.

We must show that $\rho  \circ G = I_d $, i.e $[G(z)]=[z]$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{D}$

In effect

$[G(z)]=[G(re^{i\psi})]=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \sqrt{1+r^2}e^{i\psi} & re^{i\psi}\\\  re^{-i\psi} &  \sqrt{1+r^2}e^{-i\psi}  \end{array} \right)U(1)$
$=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \sqrt{1+r^2}e^{i\psi} & re^{i\psi}\\\  re^{-i\psi} &  \sqrt{1+r^2}e^{-i\psi}  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  e^{-i\psi} & 0 \\\  0 &  e^{i\psi}  \end{array} \right)U(1)$
$=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \sqrt{1+r^2} & re^{2i\psi}\\\  re^{-2i\psi} &  \sqrt{1+r^2}  \end{array} \right)U(1)$
$=re^{i\psi}U(1)$?

My question is: can I identify the elements of $\mathbb{D}$ with those of $ \text{SU}(1,1)$ in such a way that what I intend to prove is fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify $SU(1,1)/U(1)$ with $\Bbb D$ via $g\mapsto g(0)$, where we interpret $g$ as a Mobius transformation.

The section condition now reads $G(g)(0)= e^{i\theta(z)}S(z)/C(z)=z$. Clearly $\theta(z)=\psi$. Taking absolute values, we may substitute $|S(z)|=|z||C(z)|$ into $C(z)^2-S(z)^2=1$ to solve for $C(z)$ and $S(z)$.

Comment: Hi friend. If  $|S(z)|=|z||C(z)|$ then $S(z)^2=r^2C(z)^2$. Hence $C(z)^2= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ and $S(z)^2= \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ But how do I find $g\mapsto g(0)$, $g$ Mobius transformation? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Your solution is very good, since each element of $\mathbb{D} $ can be written in the form $ z = \text{tanh} (t) e^ {i \psi} $ for some $ t>0 $, then the section is: $G(z) = G(\text{tanh}(t)e^{i\psi})=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 e^{i\psi} & 0 \\\ 0 & e^{-i\psi}  \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \text{cosh}(t)& \text{senh}(t) \\\ \text{senh}(t)  &  \text{cosh}(t)  \end{array} \right)$ and everything agrees. But how do I find $g\to g(0)$?

Comment: If $g=[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}]$ then the corresponding Mobius transformation is $g(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ so in particular $g(0)=b/d$. There is a transitive group action of $SU(1,1)$ on $\Bbb D$ by Mobius transformations, and the stabilizer of $0$ is $U(1)$, so the orbit-stabilizer theorem says we can identify $SU(1.1)/U(1)$ with $\Bbb D$ via $gU(1)\leftrightarrow g(0)$.

Comment: $e^{i\theta(z)}S(z)/C(z)=e^{i\theta(z)}\frac{\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}=re^{i\theta(z)}=z$, what does it mean $\rho(g)(0)$?$

Comment: $\rho(g)$ is an element of $SU(1,1)$, so interpreting it as a Mobius function you can evaluate it at $z=0$.

Comment: But $\rho(g)=gU(1) \leftrightarrow g(0)$. How is it possible that $\rho(g)\in \text{SU}(1,1)$?

Comment: Sorry I mixed up your letters. I guess I mean $G(g)$ not $\rho(g)$, since you want to call the section $G$.

Comment: Thanks friend, you were a great help.